# When there is a persistent connection how does a server identify subsequent request?

Tags: java, sockets

I am studying network sockets.
To my understanding ServerSocket accepts a new incoming request and returns a new socket. Now a persistent connection is established. A client and a server sockets are ready to communicate. The client sends a new request to the server host and port. Does this new request have to be handled by a ServerSocket first? Or in other words how does the server identify that this request should be handled by already existing connection?

Comment: Your question belies a deep misunderstanding of how sockets work. Once a connection is established, the communication occurs (at both ends) by reading and writing the connected socket. ServerSocket isn't involved. A "new request" on a persistent connection is just a new command sent over the existing connected socket. The identification of which socket the request happened on is done at the OS/network level.

Comment: Are you asking how TCP works?  When a new connection is established the remote IP and Port are bound to a connection and packets are automatically sequenced and retransmitted by the protocol.